# Nest Json Array merge

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, json-query

I have a column saved json data in my table:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max)
set @json = N'
{
    "Companies": [
        {
            "CompanyId": "A",
            "Employee": null
        },
        {
            "CompanyId": "B",
            "Employee": [
                {
                    "EmployeePictureId": null,
                    "Name": "Employee1"
                },
                {
                    "EmployeePictureId": "PictureId2",
                    "Name": "Employee2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "CompanyId": "C",
            "Employee": [
                {
                    "EmployeePictureId": null,
                    "Name": "Employee3"
                },
                {
                    "EmployeePictureId": null,
                    "Name": "Employee4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
'
```

Is it posible to get the result like:

```
{
   "EmployeePictureIds": ["PictureId2"]
}
```

using the `Json_Query`, `Json_Value`, `OPENJSON`...

Only get `EmployeePictureId` and skip empty(null) data

By the way, the count of elements in array are not sure.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2017 you can use the following query:

```
select json_query(QUOTENAME(STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE( A.EmployeePictureId , 'json') 
                  + '"', char(44)))) as [EmployeePictureIds]
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.Companies')
WITH 
( 
  CompanyId  NVARCHAR(MAX),
  Employee  NVARCHAR(MAX)  as json  
) as B
cross apply openjson (B.Employee)  
with  
(  
    EmployeePictureId VARCHAR(50),  
    [Name] VARCHAR(50)
) as A     
where A.EmployeePictureId is not null
for json path , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Results for the JSON you provided:

[image]

Results adding another non null `EmployeePictureId`:

[image]